# method not getting called but no error when I build

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm following along with the Stanford ios 7 course (in the third lecture) where the instructor builds a card matching game. There are twelve cards on the screen and they are hooked upto this property in the ViewController

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *cardButtons;
```

and when any of the buttons are clicked, this method is triggered

```
- (IBAction)touchCardButton:(UIButton *)sender {
      NSLog(@"touchCardbutton");

    int cardIndex = [self.cardButtons indexOfObject:sender];
    [self.game chooseCardAtIndex:cardIndex];
    [self updateUI];

}
```

which triggers updateUI in the viewController

```
- (void)updateUI{
    NSLog(@"updateUI");
    for (UIButton *cardButton in self.cardButtons){
        int index = [self.cardButtons indexOfObject:cardButton];
         NSLog(@"index in UpdateUI %d", index);
        Card *card = [self.game cardAtIndex:index];
        NSLog(@"card in UpdateUI %@", card);
        [cardButton setTitle:[self titleForCard:card ]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cardButton setBackgroundImage:[self backgroundImageForCard:card]   forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cardButton.enabled = !card.isMatched;

    }
}
```

In this updateUi method, the second NSLog statement is showing that `card` is nil. The first NSLog statement is showing the `index` without a problem. So why is `card` nil? I'm assuming that there's some problem with the cardAtIndex method in the cardMatchGame class referred to by this property in the view Controller

from the viewController
    @property (strong, nonatomic) CardMatchingGame *game;

cardAtIndex

```
-(Card *)cardAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSLog(@"cardAtIndex %d", index);
    return (index < [self.cards count]) ? self.cards[index] : nil;


}
```

This NSLog statement is not showing in the console, so it doesn't appear anything's happening when I call cardAtIndex in `updateUI`

```
Card *card = [self.game cardAtIndex:index];
```

Can you explain why the method cardAtIndex might not be getting called while there is also no error message when I build and run?

Update

In the view controller, the game property is lazily instantiated like this

```
-(CardMatchingGame *)game
{
     if (_game) _game = [[CardMatchingGame alloc] initWithCardCount:[self.cardButtons count] usingDeck:self.createDeck];

    return _game;
}
```

Comment: Log `self.game`. I guess you get `nil` and you forgot to assign it somewhere.

Comment: `cardAtIndex` will also return nil if you request a card index higher than the number of elements in the array - so your array may not be loaded correctly.  Try setting a breakpoint at `cardAtIndex` and see what is happening in that method

Comment: @Wain logging self.game said it was NULL. At the top of the ViewController I set this property `@property (strong, nonatomic) CardMatchingGame *game;` which I thought would let me call `self.game` without need to assign anything else

Comment: The `@property` just gives you an instance variable to store something in, it doesn't assign it to anything...

Comment: @Paulw11 i set a breakpoint but it's not getting triggered, which isn't surprising because the nslog in it also wasn't logging

Comment: @Wain would calling self.game trigger this getter method (also in vc) that lazily instantiates game `-(CardMatchingGame *)game
{
     if (_game) _game = [[CardMatchingGame alloc] initWithCardCount:[self.cardButtons count] usingDeck:self.createDeck];
    
    return _game;
}`

Comment: Sorry, missed where you said the NSLog in that method wasn't triggering.  @Wain is right - where do you initialise and assign a CardMatchingGame object to self.game?

Comment: @Paulw11 see my previous comment or the update in op

Comment: thanks problem figured out, the getter should have been `if (!_game)`. If you want to post an answer, I will accept it otherwise will add the answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `self.game` reference is `nil` so no call is made. No warning / error is thrown as calling `nil` is defined to do nothing.

You issue appears to stem from a logic issue in your accessor method which should be:

```
- (CardMatchingGame *)game
{
    if (!_game)
        _game = [[CardMatchingGame alloc] initWithCardCount:[self.cardButtons count] usingDeck:self.createDeck];

    return _game;
}
```

*Note the addition of the `!`*

It's usually better not to shortcut and use `if (!something)` but to be explicit and use `if (something == nil)` because it's clearer and faster to understand what's going on.